# Searching in a dataframe cell for lists of lists

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which consists of 2 columns Error and Comments
My Error column would contain a list of strings in each cell. I need help in writing code for searching through the dataframe and find the comments of that row where my Dataframe Error content matches with user input val1.

i have tried the given code but it gives the error length does not match

```
df.loc[df['Error'].values == val1, 'Comments']
```

where df is my dataframe with columns 'Error' and 'Comments'

df

```
Error                       Comments
['My data1','My data2']    'Resolution1'
['My data1','My data3']    'Resolution2'
```

Assume `val1 = ['My data1','My data2']`

My result is to find Resolution1 as output by searching the df by val1

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output? [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplist is compare lists if need exact match:

```
m = df['Error'].apply(lambda x: x == val1)
```

If order should be different, convert to sets and comapre:

```
m = df['Error'].apply(lambda x: bool(set(x) == set(val1)))
```

If need intersection:

```
m = df['Error'].apply(lambda x: bool(set(x).intersection(set(val1))))
```

Or:

```
m = ~df['Error'].map(set(val1).isdisjoint)

out = df.loc[m, 'Comments']
```

If need change value:

```
df.loc[m, 'Comments'] = 'another value'
```

Comment: will df.loc[m, 'Comments'] = 'another value'  make changes inplace?

Comment: @MayankRastogi - yes, exactly.

Comment: will this code work if i change the data in error from list of strings to list of lists?

Comment: @MayankRastogi - Then it is more complicated. Need loop for each nested list and compare. Can you add some sample data?

Comment: No need for that found a way to convert them into list of strings

Answer (score 1):

If the order is not a concern

```
df[df['Error'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x) == ' '.join(val1))]['Comments']
```

**Output**

```
0      'Resolution1'
Name:    Comments, dtype: object
```

If order is a concern

```
df[df.Error.apply(lambda x: True if len(set(x+val1)) == len(x) else False )]['Comments']
```

**Output**

```
0      'Resolution1'
Name: Comments, dtype: object
```

Comment: and can u help me in editing the contents of this comments cell after searching? For eg if i have to replace Resolution 1 with some other value...

Comment: Dont use `df[df['Error'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x) == ' '.join(val1))]['Comments']` - join by space should return wrong output and also filtering all columns by boolean indexing and then filter column is wrong concept...

Comment: But something like should solve both problems `df.loc[df['Error'].apply(lambda x: '___'.join(x) == '___'.join(val1)), 'Comments']`